# Batch find certain filenames then use the names in variable

Tags: loops, batch-file, find

I need help with a script that first finds all files in a directory with a certain string, then uses the filenames in a variable to be used in a script. 
So:

1. Find files and filenames
2. Saves file?
3. Start some kind of loop? that changes a variable then executes the
   belonging script
4. Repeat till all filenames have been used.

My code here..

```
@Echo off

For /r C:\work %%G In (*) Do @Findstr /M /S "string" > filenames.txt %%G
Set Var1=0
For %%G In (*) Do (
Var1=<filenames.txt (???)
script
script
```

I haven't writen "script" myself and friend help me with it, if you would like to see it do you need to wait until I can get to my other computer at home.

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: `I'm fairly new to scripting and batch so you all know`

Comment: `lunch at work right now` -- don't think that many would be interested in such details.

Comment: your right, the information is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Find files and filenames
> 2. Saves file

```
set "search=what I want to find"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /s "C:\work" ^| findstr "%search%"') do echo (%%~fa)>filenames.txt
```

> 1. Start some kind of loop? that changes a variable then executes the belonging script
> 2. Repeat till all filenames have been used.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filenames.txt) do (
  REM here do something inside the loop
  REM until all file names from filenames.txt were processed
)
```

Comment: inside the `for` loop you can place the actions, you need to do with the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is designed to find files in c:\work that match a string, and echo the filenames.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\work"
for %%a in ("*string*") do (
echo "%%a"
)
```